# Как сделать список рабочих ссылок по смене языка?

Tags: python, html, django

Я нашел пример с помощью которого можно менять язык опровляя пост запрос

```
{% load i18n %}

<!-- rename lang code -->
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGE %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGE as languages %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name="language">
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{language.code}}"{%if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %} >{{ language.name_local }}({{language.code }})</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="submit" name="Next" value='True'>click</button>
</form>
```

Но я хочу менять язык своего сайта с помощью ссылок
Примерно вот так

```
<ul>
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGE %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGE as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<li><a href="{{language.code}}{{ request.get_full_path }}">{{language.code}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Но проблема в том что я хочу разместить этот код в базовом шаблоне он должен показывать текущую ссылку на которой находится пользователь но с другим языком

а прописывать в каждой функций внутри views.py я не хочу. так как это лишняя писанина

как мне это сделать?

Comment: Можно попробовать написать [`Middleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#middleware).